# Bitcoin - differences between address, account and wallet

Tags: wallet, address, bitcoin-core-accounts

I've been reading official BTC documentation and now I'm completely lost. Documentations is too tangled and written in unnecessary many words.
They have:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained (no, actually not *explained*)

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet

Please, somebody tell me the difference between them in a simple manner. What's an address, an account, a wallet, and how does the keys fit in.

Comment: No, I did not, but thanks to you - now I do!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Accounts" are a concept limited to bitcoin-qt, and it's probably better to forget about them entirely.

Each address has a corresponding private key, that you use to move bitcoin out of that address. A wallet is simply a collection of (address, address_key) pairs.

Some people also use the term "wallet" to refer to the software that **implements** the wallet functionality.

---

Obviously, this is a grossly simplified answer, and not strictly true, but useful if you just want to understand bitcoin superficially.

Comment: Can you elaborate why *Accounts* should be forgotten? It is a useful feature which allows to arrange funds into buckets. Only end-single-user wallets doesn't need that feature.